# flutter - wait for camera access granted

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter app that opens the camera preview with a FutureBuilder. When the app opens for the first time, the app asks for permission. (This is triggered automatically). When I press ok I get a red screen:

[image]

I need to wait for the response, and why is dispose called?

I checked this: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

and tested this:

```
if (await Permission.contacts.request().isGranted) {
  // Either the permission was already granted before or the user just granted it.
}
```

But I got false and was never asked to approve anything. In contrast to the description.

Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:name/Model/FileIO/file_io.dart';
import 'package:name/Views/main_view.dart';
import 'package:name/main.dart';

class CameraView extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<CameraView> createState() {
    return _CameraViewState();
  }
}

class _CameraViewState extends State<CameraView> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  CameraController? controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeController;
  List<CameraDescription> rearCameras = List.empty(growable: true);
  int _currentCameraIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp
    ]);
    _ambiguate(WidgetsBinding.instance)?.addObserver(this);
    for (var description in cameras) {
      if (description.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.back) {
        rearCameras.add(description);
      }
    }
    onNewCameraSelected(rearCameras[_currentCameraIndex]);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _ambiguate(WidgetsBinding.instance)?.removeObserver(this);
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    final CameraController? cameraController = controller;
    if (cameraController == null || cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
      return;
    }

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      cameraController.dispose();
    }
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      onNewCameraSelected(rearCameras[_currentCameraIndex]);
    }
  }

  Future<void> onNewCameraSelected(CameraDescription description) async {
    if (controller != null) {
      await controller!.dispose();
    }

    final CameraController cameraController = CameraController(
      description,
      ResolutionPreset.max,
      enableAudio: false,
      imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.jpeg,
    );
    controller = cameraController;

    cameraController.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }

      if (cameraController.value.hasError) {
        showInSnackbar(
            "Camera error: ${cameraController.value.errorDescription}");
      }
    });
    try {
      _initializeController = cameraController.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      print('Error initializing camera: $e');
    }

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  Future<void> _onCameraSwitch() async {
    if (controller == null) {
      return;
    }
    _currentCameraIndex = (_currentCameraIndex + 1) % rearCameras.length;
    final CameraDescription cameraDescription =
        rearCameras[_currentCameraIndex];
    onNewCameraSelected(cameraDescription);
  }

  void showInSnackbar(String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
  }

  bool isRecording() {
    return controller != null && controller!.value.isRecordingVideo;
  }

  Widget _cameraPreviewWidget(DeviceOrientation orientation) {
    if (controller != null) {
      final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      final deviceRatio = size.width / size.height;
      controller!.lockCaptureOrientation(orientation);
      return Center(
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: deviceRatio,
          child: CameraPreview(controller!),
        ),
      );
    }
    return const Text("Camera not ready or available");
  }

  Widget _captureRowWidget() {
    final CameraController? cameraController = controller;
    return Container(
      color: const Color.fromARGB(50, 255, 255, 255),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.videocam),
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: cameraController != null &&
                    cameraController.value.isInitialized &&
                    !cameraController.value.isRecordingVideo
                ? onVideoRecordButtonPressed
                : null,
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: isRecording() ? onStopRecordingButtonPressed : null,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.stop),
          ),
          TextButton(
              onPressed: _onCameraSwitch, child: const Text("Switch Camera"))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void onVideoRecordButtonPressed() {
    startVideoRecording().then((_) => {
          if (mounted) {setState(() {})}
        });
  }

  void onStopRecordingButtonPressed() {
    stopVideoRecording().then((video) async {
      if (video != null) {
        final path = await localPath;
        final file = File('$path/video/${timestamp() + ".mp4"}');
        await file.create(recursive: true);
        video.saveTo(file.path);
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> startVideoRecording() async {
    final CameraController? cameraController = controller;
    if (cameraController == null || !cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
      showInSnackbar("Error: Camera unavailable");
      return;
    }

    if (cameraController.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      await cameraController.startVideoRecording();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
      return;
    }
  }

  Future<XFile?> stopVideoRecording() async {
    final CameraController? cameraController = controller;
    if (cameraController == null || !cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
      return null;
    }

    try {
      return cameraController.stopVideoRecording();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  OrientationBuilder getBody() {
    return OrientationBuilder(
      builder: (context, orientation) {
        var deviceOrientation = DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft;
        if (orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
          deviceOrientation = DeviceOrientation.portraitUp;
        }
        return Stack(
          children: [
            _cameraPreviewWidget(deviceOrientation),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 2,
              left: 2,
              right: 2,
              child: _captureRowWidget(),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _showCameraException(CameraException e) {
    _logError(e.code, e.description);
    showInSnackbar('Error: ${e.code}\n${e.description}');
  }

  void _navigateBack() {
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return const MainView();
        },
      ),
      (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Video Recorder"),
        leading: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            _navigateBack();
          },
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back, // add custom icons also
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FutureBuilder<void>(
            future: _initializeController,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return getBody();
              } else {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  T? _ambiguate<T>(T? value) => value;

  void _logError(String code, String? message) {
    if (message != null) {
      print('Error: $code\nError Message: $message');
    } else {
      print('Error: $code');
    }
  }

  String timestamp() {
    return DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do double check after grant permission, and if it still not granted it will show a dialog to open setting menu

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

enum CaptureMode { IDENTITY, SELFIE }

class CameraCapture extends StatefulWidget {
  Function onCaptured;
  CaptureMode captureMode;

  CameraCapture({required this.onCaptured, required this.captureMode});

  @override
  State<CameraCapture> createState() => _CameraCaptureState();
}

class _CameraCaptureState extends State<CameraCapture> {
  List<CameraDescription>? cameras;

  CameraController? cameraController;

  bool isPopupPermissionShow = false;

  _openSettingDialog(BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text("Camera permission not granted"),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                child: const Text("Open Setting"),
                onTap: () async {
                  Navigator.pop(context, null);
                  cameraController?.dispose();
                  await openAppSettings();
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
              GestureDetector(
                child: const Text("Cancel"),
                onTap: () async {
                  Navigator.pop(context, null);
                  return;
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );

  checkPermission(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      bool isCameraGranted = await Permission.camera.request().isGranted;
      if (!isCameraGranted) {
        if (!isPopupPermissionShow) {
          isPopupPermissionShow = true;
          await showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return _openSettingDialog(context);
              });
        }
        isPopupPermissionShow = false;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("camera error: " + e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<bool> setupCamera(BuildContext context) async {
    if (cameras == null) {
      cameras = await availableCameras();
    }
    if (cameraController == null || !(cameraController!.value.isInitialized)) {
      if (cameras != null && cameras!.length > 0) {
        cameraController = CameraController(
            (widget.captureMode == CaptureMode.IDENTITY)
                ? cameras!.first
                : cameras![1],
            ResolutionPreset.medium);

        try {
          await cameraController?.initialize();
        } catch (e) {
          bool isCameraGranted = await Permission.camera.request().isGranted;
          if (!isCameraGranted) {
            checkPermission(context);
          } else {
            debugPrint("camera error " + (e.toString()));
          }
        }
      } else {
        bool isCameraGranted = await Permission.camera.request().isGranted;
        if (!isCameraGranted) {
          checkPermission(context);
        } else {
          debugPrint("camera not available");
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: null,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.black),
              onPressed: () {
                cameraController?.dispose();
                widget.onCaptured("cancel");
              }),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            FutureBuilder(
                future: setupCamera(context),
                builder: (_, snapshot) {
                  return (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
                      ? CameraPreview(
                          cameraController!,
                        )
                      : Container(
                          // child: LoadingProgress(),
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: double.infinity,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        );
                }),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                //put camera mask here
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 16, left: 32, right: 32, bottom: 32),
                    child: _shutterButton(() async {
                      final image = await cameraController?.takePicture();
                      String imgPath = (image?.path ?? "");
                      cameraController?.dispose();
                    }),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _shutterButton(Function onShot) => Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 60,
            height: 60,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40), color: Colors.white),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40), color: Colors.black),
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              onShot();
            },
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
            child: Container(
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40), color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if the camera package is already asking for permission. Is it not possible to use that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, it was an incorrect if-statement.

```
 @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    final CameraController? cameraController = controller;
    if (cameraController == null || !cameraController.value.isInitialized) <-- the ! is missing in the OP {
      return;
    }

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      cameraController.dispose();
    }
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      onNewCameraSelected(rearCameras[_currentCameraIndex]);
    }
  }
```